# Error on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception ....Parameter count mismatch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, webactivator

I am getting this error after I installed Microsoft.Owin.*. 
Target .Net Framework:4.5.2. Web Activator: 2.2.0
I have the same setup in another project and that seems to work fine.
Please help me debug or fix this.

Have I have done so far:-

1. Updated all Nuget Packages
2. Deleted obj folder contents
3. Ran  aspnet_compiler.exe -p C:\source\Application\MyAPI -v anything -errorstack . It did give the same error, but stopped after I added WebMatrix.data.

Full Error Details  :-

> Parameter count mismatch. 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the   stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Stack Trace: 
[TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, 
BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,    Object[] parameters, CultureInfo 
culture) +11403690
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags 
invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[]    parameters, CultureInfo culture) +54
WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +73
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) 
+637
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +103

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method 
Run on type    WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the 
following error message: Parameter count    mismatch..]
```

Here's the package.config :-

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Answer (score 13):

I found the issue. there was another PreApplicationStartMethod in swagger that was causing the issue. 
After I removed that line things started working.

Comment: "Parameter count mismatch" is really misleading. Thanks, saved my bacon!

Comment: @RDs What do you mean by "there was another PreApplicationStartMethod in swagger"? Inside the SwaggerConfig.cs? where exactly?

Comment: @k.explorer Don't know if you're still having the issue but at the top of `SwaggerConfig.cs` is a line `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]` which can trigger this. That's what is referred to in this answer.

Comment: Yes i noticed that after a couple of hours.Thanks for checking though.cheers

Comment: "Parameter count mismatch" appears dead on to me (@StormMuller) in my case what I'd done is added an arg to the method described by the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute. But I really had no idea from the error message itself that that was the cause since nothing in the error or stack trace points to a particular attribute. 
Point is: that's what triggers it but it shouldn't if the method signature is left as it originally was (in SwaggerConfig class shipped with Swashbuckle pre-netcore library). Best not to remove the attribute, at least if you expect it to automatically load Swagger.