# IIS WebActivator does not run on IIS 10

Tags: iis, swagger, webactivator

I have a dev environment where Swagger works perfectly.

I take this same code and deploy to another environment, where I get error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +704
```

I am sure it is an environmental issue. I tried everything where I removed

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
```

and replaced it with

```
 SwaggerConfig.Register();
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

I still get the same error when I deploy the same code that just worked on another environment.

Is this an IIS Setting that I need to allow IIS to fire PreApplicationStartMethod?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551694/error-on-type-webactivatorex-activationmanager-threw-an-exception-parameter

Comment: Have tried that thanks Lex Li, was not it unfortunately